# Picker date and time type doesn't have native picker look

Tags: codenameone

When the "PICKER_TYPE_DATE_AND_TIME" type is used, the picker doesn't give native picker look. Moreover date and time overlaps each other. But if I use "PICKER_TYPE_DATE", then it works. Why is that?

```
Picker notiDateAndTime = new Picker();
notiDateAndTime.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE_AND_TIME);
notiDateAndTime.setText("Choose date and time");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using:

```
if(Display.getInstance().isNativePickerTypeSupported(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE_AND_TIME)) {
    // then decide whether to show that widget
}
```

This will return false always except for iOS which is the only platform where such a widget exists natively.

You should probably file an issue on the fallback rendering issue but notice that it never looked good even when it was working properly.

Comment: Android doesn't have a native Date & Time component. Only separate components for each.